# Python smtplib behind proxy

Tags: python, email, proxy, smtplib

I want to send an e-mail with Python, but I'm working behind a proxy and the smtplib has no proxy feature (or I haven't been able to find it). There is an open question here, but the answer does not work and has not been accepted, so I'll try to resurrect the issue here.

Any other library to send an email with Python when you are behind a proxy? (I can accept a library which is specific to Gmail)

Comment: I've made a working solution and posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69457811/5022913).