# How to send django email via proxy with authentication

Tags: python, django, email, proxy

I am trying to send an email from a work PC that is behind a proxy.

In settings.py my code looks like this:

```
    #email setup
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'username@gmail.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

In views.py:

```
    from django.core.mail import send_mail

    def home(request):
        context = RequestContext(request)
        send_mail('test email', 'hello world', 'sender@gmail.com', ['receiver@email.com'], fail_silently=False)
        return render_to_response('project/home.html', context)
```

This gives the error:

```
    [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

How can I implement authentication with the proxy?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26053352/3216909