# Gmail blocks python code trying to login from amazon server

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, smtplib

I have a python code which crawls some websites and send me some emails.
The code is working fine on my computer. Now I am trying to run the same code on an Amazon web server. However, google blocks the code. Is there any workaround?

```
import smtplib

# Send email to my personal email address
def send_email(subject, msg):
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login('e******@gmail.com', 'S****')
        message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, msg)
        server.sendmail('e*@gmail.com', 'e*@gmail.com', message)
        server.quit()
        print("Success: Email sent!")
    except:
        print("Email failed to send.")
```

Comment: Try a proxy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239797/python-smtplib-proxy-support

Comment: as I know currenty Gmail may blocks access from untrusted programs and you may have to create separated password for these programs. [Allow less secure apps to access your Gmail account](https://devanswers.co/allow-less-secure-apps-access-gmail-account/)

Comment: @furas Thanks. The app specific password works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in the comment section by Furas, Gmail may blocks access from untrusted programs and the programmer may have to create a separated password for these programs. [Allow less secure apps to access your Gmail account](https://devanswers.co/allow-less-secure-apps-access-gmail-account/)